# React child component can't get props.object

Tags: reactjs

My parent component is like this:

```
export default class MobileCompo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: null,
            datasets: {}
        };
        this.get_data = this.get_data.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.get_data();
    }


    async get_data() {
        const ret = post_api_and_return_data();
        const content={};
        ret.result.gsm.forEach((val, index) => {
            content[val.city].push()

        });
        this.setState({data: ret.result.gsm, datasets: content});
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        // I can see the value of `datasets` object
        return (
            <div>
                <TableElement dict={d} content={this.state.data} />
                <BubbleGraph maindata={this.state.datasets} labels="something"/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

child component:

```
export default class BubbleGraph extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            finalData: {datasets: []}
        };
        console.log(this.props);
        // here I can't get this.props.maindata,it's always null,but I can get labels.It's confusing me!
    }


    componentWillMount() {

        sortDict(this.props.maindata).forEach((val, index) => {
            let tmpModel = {
                label: '',
                data: null
            };
            this.state.finalData.datasets.push(tmpModel)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.props.labels}</h2>
                <Bubble data={this.state.finalData}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

I tried many times,but still don't work,I thought the reason is about `await/async`,but `TableElement` works well,also `BubbleGraph` can get `labels`.

**I also tried to give a constant to `datasets` but the child component still can't get it.And I used this:**

```
this.setState({ datasets: a});
```

**BubbleGraph works.So I can't set two states at async method?**

It is weird,am I missing something?

Any help would be great appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add   `componentWillReceiveProps` inside child componenet, and check do you get data.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)
    {
       console.log(newProps.maindata)
    }
```

If yes, the reason is `constructor` methos is called only one time. On next `setState` on parent component,`componentWillReceiveProps ()` method of child component receives new props. This method is not called on initial render.

Comment: But I still have a question,I tried to print the parent state,I can get the `datasets`,and I just use `setState` only one time,I mean,`data` and `datasets` should be updated at the same time,why `TableElement` works but `BubbleGraph` don't?

Comment: when you load parent component, it renders child coponenet as well. So you are getting static values in props. Once async call is done, setState re-renders the child component,and this time constructor method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Few Changes in Child component:

*As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state), **Never mutate state variable directly** by `this.state.a=''` or `this.state.a.push()`, always use `setState` to update the `state` values.

*use `componentwillrecieveprops` it will get called on whenever any change happen to `props` values, so you can avoid the `asyn` also, whenever you do the changes in `state` of parent component all the child component will get the updates values.

Use this child component:

```
export default class BubbleGraph extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            finalData: {datasets: []}
        };
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(newData) {
        let data = sortDict(newData.maindata).map((val, index) => {
            return {
                label: '',
                data: null
            };
        });
        let finalData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.finalData));
        finalData.datasets = finalData.datasets.concat(data);
        this.setState({finalData});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.props.labels}</h2>
                <Bubble data={this.state.finalData}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```